# App does not open on the Android emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I run my application in Android Studio, the app is successfully installed on the emulator, but when the app opens it is stuck on a screen with a white background and the Android logo. Sometimes, it also happens that when opening the app, it goes to this white screen with the Android logo and then closes the app.

AVD: Pixel 7 VanillaIceCream API

[Android emulator printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHXQR.png)

I tested it by running the application on my physical mobile device, and it is running correctly and without problems. So I believe the problem is with the emulator itself.

Comment: Have you wiped the data of the virtual device? Have you tried another virtual device? For me, wiping the data works most of the time.